# change array to json

Tags: javascript, json, casperjs

I've been playing around with javascript and casperjs. I have the following lines of code.

```
casper.thenOpen('somesite', function() {

    console.log('clicked ok, new location is ' + this.getCurrentUrl());

    // Get info on all elements matching this CSS selector
    var town_selector = 'div tr';
    var town_names_info = this.getElementsInfo(town_selector); // an array of object literals

    // Pull out the town name text and push into the town_names array
    var town_names = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < town_names_info.length; i++) {
    town_names.push(town_names_info[i].text.trim());}

    // Dump the town_names array to screen
    utils.dump(town_names);    

    casper.capture('capture5.png');
});
```

my output is this.

```
[
    "Address:\n        \n address",
    "City:\n        \ncity",
    "State:\n        \nstate",
    "Zip:\n        \nzip",
]
```

how can I make it json? like this.

```
{
    "Address":"address",
    "City":"city",
    "State":"state",
    "Zip":"zip"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
function arrayToObject(arr) {
  var out = {};
  arr.forEach(function (element) {
    var keyvalue = element.replace(/[\n\s]+/, '').split(':');
    var key = keyvalue[0];
    var value = keyvalue[1];
    out[key] = value;
  });
  return out;
}
```

then you can do:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(arrayToObject(myArray));
```

**Update**:

`> How can I change this to split only the first occurrence of colon?`

Use this:

```
arr.forEach(function (element) {
  var keyvalue = element.replace(/[\n\s]+/, '');
  var key = keyvalue.substring(0, element.indexOf(':'));
  var value = keyvalue.substring(key.length + 1);
  out[key] = value;
});
```

Comment: not sure why. buy my output is this. `{
    \"Address\": \"address\",
    \"City\": \"city\",
    \"State\": \"state\",
    \"Zip\": \"zip\"
}`

Comment: changing line to `var json = arrayToObject(myArray);` did it for me. thanks.

Comment: how can I change this to split only the first occurrence of colon ? I have some lines like such "Planned Start:08:16 AM" my output is "Planned Start":"08" I tried "var keyvalue = element.split(':',1);" but that didn't work.